# node.js + socket.io + recursively adding replies

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've cobbled together a web page to control an Onkyo receiver via its serial port using parts of several diverse examples I found mostly on stackexchange. It works well, but I've run into the problem highlighted by @user568109 in the first link below where I think I have "initialized connection eventlisteners from within your routes" instead of globally. (Each time the web page is refreshed, the number of replies sent increments by one.) The problem is I can't see how to do initialize it globally. I tried removing the function:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {......}
```

but leaving the ....... part, as was done successfully in the second link below, but that didn't work for my case. Is there a simple fix? I'm a complete novice to node and javascript so I'm hoping it is obvious to someone.

Apart from the additional replies each time the web page is refreshed, it works well. (Apart from initializing the on off switch, the radio buttons and volume slider get initialed correctly, but I'll try to address that once I've sorted this sockets thing out).
Thanks!

[Socket.io emits duplicate data after browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623555/socket-io-emits-duplicate-data-after-browser-refresh)

[node.js + socket.io - duplicate websocket writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392316/node-js-socket-io-duplicate-websocket-writes)

Here's the code snippet:

```js
var express = require('express');
app   = express();
server   = require('http').createServer(app);
io    = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var SerialPort = require("serialport")
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", { 
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: 'none',
  stopBits: 1
    }
 );
server.listen(8080);
app.use(express.static('public'));             
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('toOnkyo', function (data) {
                paramVal = data.value;
                var buf = new Buffer(16);                
    buf.write(paramVal, "utf-8");
                serialPort.write(buf);
    io.sockets.emit('toOnkyo', {value: paramVal});   
    });

  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    io.sockets.emit('onkyoReply', {value: data.toString().substr(0,7)});
    });
  
});
console.log("running");
```

```css
body {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background: #50D0A0;
}

input[type=range]{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 80%;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 height: 10px;
 background: #ddd;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border: none;
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: goldenrod;
 margin-top: -12px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
 outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 background: #ccc;
}
.radioLeft
{
    text-align:left;
}



.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Onkyo Controller</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=400px" />
        <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

Sent:  <span id="sliderVolText"></span><br>
Reply:  <span id="replyTextHex"></span>
(Decimal: <span id="replyText10"></span>)<br>
Mode:  <span id="modeText"></span><br>
PowerText: <span id="powerText"></span><br>
Power:  <span id="power"></span><br>
onoffText: <span id="onoffText"></span><br>
onoff:  <span id="onoff"></span>  

 <script>
 function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
  if(!radioObj)
   return;
  var radioLength = radioObj.length;
  if(radioLength == undefined) {
   radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
   return;
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
   radioObj[i].checked = false;
   if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
    radioObj[i].checked = true;
   }
  }
 }
 </script>

 <form class="onoffswitch" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch"  onclick="showOnoff(checked)">
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
 </form>

 <form name="modeForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <p>   <label for="mode0"><input type="radio" value="0x00" name="modeForm" id="mode0" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> Stereo</label>
  &nbsp;<label for="mode1"><input type="radio" value="0x01" name="modeForm" id="mode1" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> Direct</label>
  &nbsp;<label for="mode2"><input type="radio" value="0x0C" name="modeForm" id="mode2" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> All Ch stereo</label>
  &nbsp;<label for="mode3"><input type="radio" value="0x42" name="modeForm" id="mode3" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> THX Cinema</label>
  &nbsp;<label for="mode4"><input type="radio" value="0x84" name="modeForm" id="mode4" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> PLllx THX Cinema</label>
  &nbsp;<label for="mode5"><input type="radio" value="0x11" name="modeForm" id="mode5" onclick="showMode(this.value)"> Pure</label>
 </form>

 <form name="slideForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="range" id= "inputSlider" min="0" max="100" value="vol" step="1" oninput="showVolume(this.value)" />
 </form>

 <br><br>
 <div class="results"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect();
  var ctrlType = "";
   socket.on('toOnkyo', function (data) {
    ctrlType = data.value.toString().substr(2,3);
    if (ctrlType == "MVL" && !(data.value.toString().substr(5,4)=="QSTN")){
     document.getElementById("inputSlider").value =  parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     document.getElementById("sliderVolText").innerHTML = data.value;
    }
    if (ctrlType == "LMD" && !(data.value.toString().substr(5,4)=="QSTN")){
     document.getElementById("mode").value =  parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     document.getElementById("modeText").innerHTML = data.value;
    }
    if (ctrlType == "PWR" && !(data.value.toString().substr(5,4)=="QSTN") ){
     document.getElementById("power").value =  parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     document.getElementById("powerText").innerHTML = data.value;
    }
    if (ctrlType == "PWR" && !(data.value.toString().substr(5,4)=="QSTN") ){
     document.getElementById("onoff").value =  parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     document.getElementById("onoffText").innerHTML = data.value;
    }
   });
            socket.on('onkyoReply', function (data) {
                var done = false;
    ctrlType = data.value.toString().substr(2,3);
    document.getElementById("replyTextHex").innerHTML = data.value;
    document.getElementById("replyText10").innerHTML = parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
    if (ctrlType == "LMD"){
     setCheckedValue(document.forms['modeForm'].elements['modeForm'],"0x"+data.value.toString().substr(5,2));
    }
    if (ctrlType == "PWR"){
     var val = parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     setCheckedValue(document.forms['powerForm'].elements['powerForm'],"0x"+data.value.toString().substr(5,2));
    }
    if (ctrlType == "MVL" && done == false){
     document.getElementById("inputSlider").value = parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = parseInt(data.value.toString().substr(5,2),16);
     done = true;      
    }
   });

   function showVolume(newValue) {      
          document.getElementById("sliderVolText").innerHTML="\!1MVL"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n";
                socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1MVL"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n" });
   }

   function showMode(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("modeText").innerHTML="\!1LMD"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n";
                socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1LMD"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n" });
   }

   function showOnoff(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("onoffText").innerHTML="\!1PWR"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n";
    socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1PWR"+("0" + Number(newValue).toString(16)).slice(-2)+"\r\n" });
   }

   socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1PWRQSTN"+"\r\n" });
   socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1LMDQSTN"+"\r\n" });
   socket.emit('toOnkyo', { value: "\!1MVLQSTN"+"\r\n" });
   
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution based on Ian Wooten's blog:

http://www.ianwootten.co.uk/2011/07/04/maintaining-references-to-sockets-with-express-and-socket-io/

Great!

```js
server.listen(8080);
app.use(express.static('public'));             
var paramVal = 0;
var countRep = 0;
var countSend = 0;
var buf = new Buffer(16);
var global_socket;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  global_socket = socket;
        global_socket.on('toOnkyo', function (data) {
                paramVal = data.value;
    buf.write(paramVal, "utf-8");
                serialPort.write(buf);
    console.log(paramVal.toString().substr(0,7) + " (" + parseInt(paramVal.toString().substr(5,2),16) + ")\r\n");    
                global_socket.emit('toOnkyo', {value: paramVal});   
    console.log('new'+paramVal);
    countSend=countSend+1;
    console.log('count send '+ countSend);
    
    });
});
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data.toString().substr(0,7) + " (" + parseInt(data.toString().substr(5,2),16) + ")");
    global_socket.emit('onkyoReply', {value: data.toString().substr(0,7)});
    countRep=countRep+1;
    console.log('count '+ countRep);
    });

console.log("running");
```